# Phantom redirect?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've gone through my hosting company, removed/edited wordpress settings that might be causing it, looked at my htaccess and still can't figure out why this site is coming back as 'redirected too many times' when accessed through Google Webmaster Tools, Twitter Card Validator, and some other scanning tools.

[Here](http://spencerelrod.com) is the site, and I'm wondering if there's a way I can diagnose it using the network debug tool in a browser?  I just can't figure out where the redirect is being generated because dreamhost (ugh) says they can't detect any issues.

Thanks very much

EDIT:
**here's a security plugin the website is using**

**Bulletproof security:**

Website Security Protection: BulletProof Security protects your website against XSS, RFI, CRLF, CSRF, Base64, Code Injection and SQL Injection... hacking attempts. One-click .htaccess WordPress security protection. Protects wp-config.php, bb-config.php, php.ini, php5.ini, install.php and readme.html with .htaccess security protection. Security Logging. HTTP Error Logging. Login Security/Login Monitoring: Log All Account Logins or Log Only Account Lockouts. Website FrontEnd/BackEnd Maintenance Mode (HTTP 503). Additional website security checks: DB errors off, file and folder permissions check... System Info: PHP, MySQL, OS, Server, Memory Usage, IP, SAPI, DNS, Max Upload... Built-in .htaccess file Editor.

EDIT:  Google webmaster tools is getting the following crawl errors
?s=%7Bsearch_term%7D
and
search/%7Bsearch_term%7D/

Comment: Cleared your browser cache yet?

Comment: Hi Jack, check this out - if you use https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator to scan the site http://spencerelrod.com the error is what I describe.  so It can't be my cache que no?

Comment: Do you have any redirect type plugin installed with WP?

Comment: Good question, I added the details of a WP security plugin the site is using is it possibly related?  Thanks Panama

Answer (score 1):

Might be a canonical issue. Do you have a google webmaster acct for spencerelrod.com? Could be reverberating between the www and the non-www.

UPDATE

Check [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-error-too-many-redirects-issue-in-wordpress/)

Comment: yea I do have a webm account, the www is the preferred version and is successfully submitting to index in that regard. adding google webm crawl errors as edit to post